# How to detect android application paused on library?

Tags: android, android-library

I have a android lib contains a custom Webview. When the application which use my lib paused or resumed I want my custom Webview don't load data anymore and this will be handled on my lib, not on the application. So, how can I know when the app is paused or resume from my android library?

Comment: Are you sure that you can continue using a WebView if the activity is being paused?

Comment: From logcat i saw that onPageFinished(..) still running, it means WebView is still loading data.

Comment: I am also looking for this function. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Run the webview load function in a thread. and pause or resume the thread on onPause or onResume event respectively.

For that you need to [override `onPause`-](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) and [`onResume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29)

See this for how to pause/resume thread.
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/PauseThread.html

---

I am not sure that i understood your question completely. But from your question `"how can I know when the app is paused or resume from my android library?"`, i mean that you want to detect the onPause and onResume events in library class and let other user use it.

In this case , i think the following would be the solution.

**Do this :**

```
//for your library 
public class LibraryWebViewActivity extends Activity{
//override onPause and onResume here 

}


//to be used by users of library :
public class UserLibraryWebViewActivity extends LibraryWebViewActivity{

//override onCreate....and other method here....

}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, but I want to know when the onPause and onResume occured on my library, not on the application use my library.

Comment: what you are referring by my library?? onPause event occurs when you press back on your app and your app goes to background. and onresume occurs when you later open the app, which has been to background previously.

Comment: He is providing a customised webview (+probably more) that other people would implement into their activities - so he has no control over what their activities do.

Comment: Yes, I know the activity lifecycle. But in this case, I want to know when the application paused or resumed from a lib, which used by the application, not from the application.
Sorry, English is not my mother tongue, so my question maybe not clear :(

Comment: @Wayne i have added another solution.. read and comment on that

Comment: Thanks you, but first, my class already axtended another superclass, so I cannot extends Activity. Second, how the onPause, onResume  methods invoked from the lib ?

Comment: If UserLibraryWebViewActivity is currently running, then the events  onResume/onPause will be handled from LibraryWebViewActivity class. Because class UserLibraryWebViewActivity extends LibraryWebViewActivity  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 0):

I would make your webview have its own pause and resume methods that the user of your library has to call from their activities. You could throw an IllegalStateException when doing any loading if resume hasn't been called, but it depends how strict you want to be.

Comment: Thanks you but I want to handle WebView's pause and resume methods on the lib by myself, and who use my lib don't know about this.

Comment: Could make a WebViewActivity that they have to extend instead of Activity (not nice if they want a MapActivity or something like WebtrendsActivity).. or you could check to see which application is in the foreground every 500ms or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solution:

Because my customized WebView is still loading data when app paused so onPageStarted(..) also running too. To check whether the app is paused or not, I just simply used isShown() method. Of course, this is only true in my case because my customized WebView is always shown if the app is running.

Thanks you all for the replies!